# Table JQuery slice remove

Tags: jquery, html-table, slice

I am really confused with the behavior. Any help will be appreciated on this. I have a simple table and it is behaving differently though using the same JQuery call.

```
<table class="PrintTable">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr><th>Type Of Transaction</th></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Age</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr><th>2006</th></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Andi</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>25</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr><th>2007</th></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>tom</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>26</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
     </tr>
</table><script>$('table.PrintTable >tbody>tr>td').slice(-2).remove();</script>
```

The above JQuery removes the last two columns which is expected.

But, if I changed the code to:-

```
  function getBody(element)
    {
        var divider=2;
        var originalTable=element.clone();
        var newTable = ($(originalTable).children('tbody').children('tr').children('td')).slice(-1).remove();
        return $('<div>').append(newTable).html();
    }

 getBoby($('table.PrintTable'))
```

The above code displays only the last column. Why is it so? I hop I am able to mention my problem properly. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What would you like the result(s) to be? Assuming the above is the before, can you post an "after" (or what you'd like received back from `getBody`)? (Also, for anyone wanting a fiddle to play with: http://www.jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/8W5Cg/ )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, it seems you want a duplicate of the original, but without the last two columns.

Do this:

```
function getBody(element) {
    var divider=2;
    var newTable = element.clone();
    newTable.children('tbody').children('tr').children('td').slice(-2).remove();
    return $('<div>').append(newTable).html();
}

getBody($('table.PrintTable'));
```

In your code, `newTable` was referencing the portion of the clone that you sliced and removed. Not the main cloned table.

Comment: @Nrusingha: You're welcome. FYI, if the cloned table is going to be inserted (in other words, if you don't really need the HTML string), you can just return the cloned table. `return newTable;`

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is because you're using `slide(-1)` in the `getBody()` function, and `slice(-2)` in the first jQuery call.
slice(-2) is returning 2 columns, and slice(-1) is only returning one column.

Additionally, you don't have to call `children()` multiple times, you could just use `$element.find('tbody > tr > td');`

Comment: They do that in the first call. I'm betting it has something to do with what they're passing `getBody()` and that it should be `getBody($('table.PrintTable table'))` instead (but I don't know the intended result).

Comment: @Brad Christie: Hm, that makes me think that perhaps he's wanting a duplicate of the first table less the last two columns. But because he's using slice(-1) it's returning just the last column for the new table. Perhaps the slice(-1) and slice(-2) had me confused to the real question here. I'll update my answer in a moment. -- You don't want to use $('table.PrintTable table') as that would be looking for a nested table within the PrintTable, which is there, but you don't want to do that in this case.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. You assumption is right. I want the same table in a pop up window without the last two columns. The selectors that you have mentioned will also look into nested table. In the first scenario that I had mentioned, it is removing the column properly, but in the next scenario even if I put slice(-2).remove(), it displays only the removed columns.